# Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, lambda, repository

In my controller i am trying to use include with EF4 to select related entities, but the lambda expression is throwing the following error,

i have the related entity defined in the Entity class like

```
public class CustomerSite
{
    public int CustomerSiteId { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Then in my controller i have

```
 var sites = context.CustomerSites.Include(c => c.Customer);

 public ViewResult List()
 {
    var sites = context.CustomerSites.Include(c => c.Customer);
    return View(sites.ToList());
 }
```

Can anyone kindly point me in the right direction on what i'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`Include`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbquery.include%28v=VS.103%29.aspx) method expects a string, not a lambda:

```
public ViewResult List()
{
    var sites = context.CustomerSites.Include("Customer");
    return View(sites.ToList());
}
```

Of course you could write a [custom extension method](http://tomlev2.wordpress.com/2010/10/03/entity-framework-using-include-with-lambda-expressions/) which would work with lambda expressions and make your code independant of some magic strings and refactor friendlier.

But whatever you do PLEASE OH PLEASE don't pass EF autogenerated objects to your views. **USE VIEW MODELS**.

Comment: thanks, but easier said than done, i cant find a solid example of how to use view models to return related data

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov Could you please come look at a similar question i have posted. http://stackoverflow.com/q/16060884/1356321

Comment: Could you please give a reference to the update below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9428710/1268910

Comment: Definitely check out the alternate answer for later versions of Entity Framework, as lambdas are allowed.

Comment: Above answer is out-of-date.  Correct answer is below.
```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

Answer (score 97):

Well, the post is quite old, but just replying here to update it. Well, the `Include()` method with **Entity Framework 4.1** has extension methods and it also accepts a lambda expression. So

```
context.CustomerSites.Include(c => c.Customer);
```

is perfectly valid, all you need to do is use this:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

Answer (score 13):

Include is an extension method in the System.Data.Entity namespace, you need to add:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

Then you can use the lambda expression, instead of the string.

Answer (score 2):

`Include` takes a string, not a lambda expression.
Change it to `CustomerSites.Include("Customer")`

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting this error in Razor:

Ex:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Security, "Fixed", new { @id = "securityFixed"})
```

C# doesn't know how to convert the string to valid bool or known type.

So change your string as below:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Security, "True", new { @id = "securityFixed"})
```

or

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Security, "False", new { @id = "securityFixed"})
```