# Cannot convert lambda expression to type “string” because it is not a delegate type?

Tags: c#, lambda, asp.net-mvc-5

```
       var viewModel = new CoachIndexData();

        viewModel.Coaches = db.Coaches
            .Include(i => i.Courses.Select(c => c.Department))
            .OrderBy(i => i.LastName);
```

I Can not Understand how to do it. I am new in ASP.NET MVC

Comment: Can you show your code for the view model?

Answer (score 6):

Taken from [Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696348/cannot-convert-lambda-expression-to-type-string-because-it-is-not-a-delegate-t)

This worked for me.

The Include() method with Entity Framework 4.1 has extension methods and it also accepts a lambda expression. So

```
context.CustomerSites.Include(c => c.Customer);
```

is perfectly valid, all you need to do is use this:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue lies on this line:

```
.Include(i => i.Courses.Select(c => c.Department))
```

The `Include` method, as described in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696785%28v=vs.113%29.aspx), expects a string parameter not a lambda expression.

You need to provide `Include` with the path to "navigate" (i.e. how the navigation properties are set up on your context) to the required information. In your case I believe this would be:

```
.Include("Department")
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Not sure what the case was as at May 2014, but using strings is the "old way". OP's code is correct. Strong types in the lambda is preferred. He was just missing a using statement System.Data.Entity. [Doco here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.103).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I have Same Problem and I solved with following

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic;
using System.Linq;
```

code here..

```
public IPagedList<Inv_AMC> Gets(int? page, int? pageSize, string sort = "Id", string sortdir = "DESC", string searchKey = "")
        {
            int pageIndex = page.HasValue ? Convert.ToInt32(page) : 1;
            int pageSizeValue = pageSize.HasValue ? Convert.ToInt32(pageSize) : 10;
            return dbSet.Where(x => (x.Customer.CustomerName.ToUpper().Contains(searchKey.ToUpper()) || searchKey == ""))
                  .OrderBy(sort + " " + sortdir)
                  .ToPagedList(pageIndex, pageSizeValue);
        }
```

Where Inv_AMC and Customer is db object and references each other.